# Publishing MQTT messages with a specific frequency

Tags: python, mqtt, publish, broker

I am trying to implement a Python script using Paho-MQTT to publish MQTT QoS 2 messages to a topic with a fixed frequency (20Hz).

My current code is this (msg_size, msg_amount and msg_freq are fixed parameters from a .json config file):

```
class MQTT_Client:
    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc==0:
            logging.info(f"Connected to the broker at {broker_address}")
        else:
            logging.info(f"Error connecting to broker, with code {rc}")

        self.client.subscribe(begin_client, 0)
        self.client.subscribe(finish_client, 0)
        logging.info(f"Subscribed to {begin_client} and {finish_client} topics with QoS 0")

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        if str(msg.topic) == begin_client:
            logging.info(f"Start order received from the server")
            self.msg_handler()
        elif str(msg.topic) == finish_client:
            logging.info(f"Finish order received from the server")
            self.client.disconnect()

    def on_publish(self, client, userdata, mid):
        self.counter += 1

    def on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc):
        logging.info(f"Disconnected from broker at {broker_address}")

    def msg_handler(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        payload = bytearray(msg_size)
        logging.info(f"Starting publish of {msg_amount} messages with QoS 2")
        for msg in range(msg_amount):
            self.client.publish(main_topic, payload, qos=2)
            time.sleep(1/msg_freq)
        logging.info(f"Publish complete")

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        logging.info(f"Creating MQTT Client with ID {client_id}")
        self.client = mqtt.Client(client_id=client_id)
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        self.client.on_publish = self.on_publish
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.connect(broker_address, 1883, 60)
        self.client.loop_forever()

mqtt_client = MQTT_Client()
```

The issue is that this will group up all messages while it iterates through the range (because the time.sleep() will block the networking loop, I understand that), and will then publish them all in bulk, which is not the desired effect. What I want is to publish one by one to the broker but make sure that each one is published only every 50 milliseconds.

If I take out the time.sleep() it works as intended but I obviously don't have control over the frequency in there. I tried already using a client.loop() and client.loop_start() and client.loop_stop() before the publish() command but it just locks the script and doesn't send anything. Is there any way to make it only publish every 50 milliseconds WHILE NOT blocking the network loop?

Thank you!

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75792266/edit) the question to show more of your code, specifically so we can see how you have set up the client and are running the loop. (`client.loop_start()` specifically starts the network loop on a separate thread, so there must be something else wrong with your code)

Comment: Also with QOS 2, that's not going to be as accurate as you think, as there is a network latency for the 2 way handshake on each publish (and the max inflight messages settings) to contend with.

Comment: @hardillb just edited to include the full class. I know that QoS 2 needs a bigger handshake, and I will vary the frequency according to it as well, if I can't go as low as 20Hz I want to try and find a more comfortable setting

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem is clearer now we have all the code.

The problem is that you are calling the publishing loop from within in the `on_message` callback (via a second function). This will not work for QOS 1 or 2 messages because the `on_message` callback is run on the network loop, but the network loop is also required to handle the QOS 1 or 2 handshake packets (which it can't do until `on_message` returns). Hence the lock up.

Your only option is to start a second thread to run the `msg_handler` function so the `on_message` callback can return near instantly and then handle the packets need to complete the QOS handshake.

e.g. add `import threading`

and then have `on_message` look something like:

```
    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        if str(msg.topic) == begin_client:
            logging.info(f"Start order received from the server")
            self.msg_handler()
            x = threading.Thread(target=self.msg_handler, args=())
            x.start()
        elif str(msg.topic) == finish_client:
            logging.info(f"Finish order received from the server")
            self.client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, was very helpful to understand the core issue in this! I will then modify my program to avoid this lockup